# facebook api issue in ie8

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer-8, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [fb:serverfbml won’t render on Opera and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228876/fbserverfbml-wont-render-on-opera-and-ie)

facebook funpage api working all browser but not working in IE8.

I have tried the following attempts but not succeeded any one can suggest the better way?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">FB.init("1690883eb733618b294e98cb1dfba95a");</script>
<fb:fan profile_id="<?php echo $this->config->get('my_facebook_id'); ?>" stream="0" connections="25" logobar="0" border="white" width="1170" height="94" css="<?php echo HTTPS_SERVER; ?>stylesheet/facebook.css?3.0.0.2"></fb:fan>
```

See error Screenshot : http://demo.harnishdesign.net/api-i8-issue.jpg

where i am doing wrong??? please let me know

Answer (score 3):

'Internet Explorer' needs the "Facebook namespace" defined in the "html" tag.

Here it is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but not solved my issue. I have put error screenshot link see :http://demo.harnishdesign.net/api-i8-issue.jpg & then let me know